# How can I simulate gravity correctly in a bounded area?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to do a container with balls inside, attracted to the floor like gravity. I'm close to doing it well but the balls eventually melt into each other then don't preserve their visibility.

[See the demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/04bxv2zw/2/)

I think the problem comes from the gravity function itself because the radius of each node isn't into account:

```
var gravity = function() {
    return function(d) {
        d.y += (d.cy - d.y);
        d.x += (d.cx - d.x);
    };
}
```

or from the bounding function in the simulation animation (tick), for the same problem above

```
d3.selectAll("circle.node")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
  .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
```

How can I separate each ball distinctly in this case?

*Edit: i found the solution i ll share it soon*

Comment: You can use the [collision force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#collision) `d3.forceCollide` to prevent overlapping. Have a look at the amazing Block [*Mixing drinks on Tralfamadore*](https://bl.ocks.org/monfera/2d2809d8458ffb81cc9acab2e65ed4ef) which implements a custom gravity function and uses `d3.forceCollide` to keep the points apart.

Comment: I ever saw this example but i didnt success to integrate it as i would want.. this demo uses a custom script with a wave, i ll try one more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally read the docs and understood the problem !

**[See the demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/04bxv2zw/17/)**

All is about the collide between each node, to integrate it correctly in the forceSimulation, and the bound calculation in the tick function:

```
...


  // Change values below to modify the physic
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .velocityDecay(0.3)
    .force("y", d3.forceY(height).strength(.035)) // gravity at bottom
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(radius).strength(1.5).iterations(10))
    .nodes(nodes)
    .on('tick', tick);

  function tick() {
    // bound
    node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
  }
```

Comment: Your interpretation is wrong; you can safely delete the line you marked as being the *key* without making much of a difference. Like I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491128/how-can-i-simulate-gravity-correctly-in-a-bounded-area#comment79949728_46491128) on your question it is `d3.forceCollide` which keeps the circles apart. Have a look at this modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL7ayj2z/) for a demo.  The link force will even counteract the repellant force of `forceCollide` by pulling the nodes together.

Comment: good job, i'm new with d3.js, i need to learn it more yet, i update the answer. thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library called [planck.js](https://github.com/shakiba/planck.js). I know it has nothing to do with D3 but you can always check the code in order to get some inspiration.

Good luck!

Comment: This would be better as a comment, as it is a "link-only" answer.

Comment: Link is answer not working, should be https://github.com/shakiba/planck.js